# How to use/convert my R vector object in a rest (est.ensembl.org) api query?

Tags: json, r, rest

Good morning.

I want to use the the following rest: https://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/sequence_id_post

I have the vector object (ids) in R:

```
> ids
 [1] "NM_007294.3:c.932_933insT"       "NM_007294.3:c.1883C>T"           "NM_007294.3:c.2183A>C"          
 [4] "NM_007294.3:c.2321C>T"           "NM_007294.3:c.4585G>A"           "NM_007294.3:c.4681C>A"
```

I have to put this vector(ids) with more than 200 variables in the **body= ids** variable (bellow), according to the example of code below, for it works:

Code:

library(httr)

library(jsonlite)

library(xml2)

server <- "https://rest.ensembl.org"

ext <- "/vep/human/hgvs"

r <- POST(paste(server, ext, sep = ""), content_type("application/json"), accept("application/json"), body = '{ "hgvs_notations" : ["NM_007294.3:c.932_933insT",  "NM_007294.3:c.1883C>T"] }')

stop_for_status(r)

head(fromJSON(toJSON(content(r))))

I know it's a json format, but when I convert my variable ids to json it's not in the correct format.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks for any help.

Leandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `NM_007294.3:c.2321C>T` is not a valid query to /sequence/id REST endpoint. It contains a sequence id (NM_007294.3) and a variant (c.2321C>T) and if you understood this literally, you are asking the server a letter `T`, since this call returns sequences.

Valid query would contain only sequence ids and you can use it like that (provided you have your ids in a vector):

`r <- POST(paste(server, ext, sep = ""), content_type("application/json"), accept("application/json"), body = paste0('{ "ids" :', jsonlite::toJSON(ids), ' }')`

Depending on the downstream scenario, making your ids unique might help/speed things up.

Comment: Dear  PSzczesny, the code above work.
but I have my initial data in vector object:

ids [1] "NM_007294.3:c.932_933insT" "NM_007294.3:c.1883C>T" "NM_007294.3:c.2183A>C" [4] "NM_007294.3:c.2321C>T" "NM_007294.3:c.4585G>A" "NM_007294.3:c.4681C>A"

and need to put this input automatically in format exactly like:

body = '{ "ids" : ["NM_000057.2:c.2258T>A", "NM_007294.3:c.932_933insT" ] }')

Comment: OK, your code doesn't work for me (returns "Nothing found"), but nevertheless the vector could be transformed into JSON array via jsonlite::toJSON(vector.of.ids), as I've mentioned above.